# How do I read an array in which I put elements from a binary file?

Tags: c, arrays, file, binary, structure

So what have I done is

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
int osobna;
char prezime[50+1];
char ime[50+1];
int dan,mj,god;
char ulica[100+1];
int broj;
char grad[30+1];
}glasac;

int main()
{
    FILE *fin = fopen ("puk.dat","rb");
    fseek(fin,0,SEEK_END);
    int n = ftell(fin) / sizeof(glasac);
    rewind(fin);
    glasac *niz = (glasac*)calloc(sizeof(glasac),n);
    fread(&niz[0],sizeof(glasac),n,fin);
    fclose(fin);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fprintf(fin,"%d| %s| %s| %d.%d.%d| %s| %d| %s \n",niz[i]->osobna,niz[i]->prezime,niz[i]->ime,niz[i]->dan,niz[i]->mj,niz[i]->god,niz[i]->broj,niz[i]->grad);
    }
     return 0;
}
```

I know the code is poorly stylized and it need a lot of polishing and I apologise for not naming variables in english. Why won't this print work, why can't I read what I have put in that array? 
Much thanks and love to you all!

Comment: `fprintf(fin...` - you are printing it *back* into the same file? Which is already closed.

Comment: (1) Without seeing the code that wrote the file, there's no way to know what's in it. (2) Withouth checking the return values of fopen(), fread(), etc., there's no way to know whether they succeeded or not.

Comment: I thought I could see the print in console?

Comment: `printf` yes. `fprintf(fin,...` - no.

Comment: OT: regarding functions calls like: `FILE *fin = fopen ("puk.dat","rb");
    fseek(fin,0,SEEK_END);
    int n = ftell(fin) / sizeof(glasac);`  Always check the returned value(s) to assure the operation was successful.  Otherwise, when things go wrong, the program will keep running and things will go 'bad' in a hurry

Comment: Note: the returned type from `ftell()` is a `off_t`, not a `int`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  It produces a LONG list of errors and warnings.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Comment: OT: regarding: `fprintf(fin,"%d| %s| %s| %d.%d.%d| %s| %d| %s \n",niz[i]->osobna,niz[i]->prezime,niz[i]->ime,niz[i]->dan,niz[i]->mj,niz[i]->god,niz[i]->broj,niz[i]->grad);`  It is best to honor the right margin (usually column 72 or 80) so printing works well can there is no need to be horizontally scrolling the terminal.

Comment: regarding: `glasac *niz = (glasac*)calloc(sizeof(glasac),n);`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that cast.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `fread(&niz[0],sizeof(glasac),n,fin);`  `n` is the total number of bytes in the file, NOT the number of instances of a `glasac`  Therefore, this statement will try to read way beyond the end of the file!  This will also eliminate the ability to check the returned value against the third parameter to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest:  `ssize_t count = n/sizeof(glasac);  ssize_t numRead = fread( &niz[0], sizeof (glasac ), count, fin );  if( numRead < 0 ) { // handle error }; elseif( numRead == 0 ) { //handle error } elseif( count != numRead)  { //handle error }`

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; i < n; i++){`  This will loop the number of bytes in the file.  1) this will result in accessing way beyond the end of the allocated memory, which results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event  Suggest the limit value be the result of `n/sizeof( glasac )`

Comment: due to: `FILE *fin = fopen ("puk.dat","rb");`  the file is only opened for read, not write, so this statement: `fprintf(fin,"%d| %s| %s| %d.%d.%d| %s| %d| %s \n",niz[i]->osobna,niz[i]->prezime,niz[i]->ime,niz[i]->dan,niz[i]->mj,niz[i]->god,niz[i]->broj,niz[i]->grad);` will fail

Comment: regarding the format string; `"%d| %s| %s| %d.%d.%d| %s| %d| %s `  the output format specifiers: `%s` require NUL terminated strings (and in this case, all the strings for a specific field must be NUL terminated and of the same length.  This is (probably) not the case with the data read from a binary file.